# Can't change the column properties in a table in a database in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, visual-web-developer

When I try to edit the Identity Specification from No to Yes there isn't a way to do so. No drop-down arrow or any way to edit the text. How can I change it so that I can actually change the value to 'Yes'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was in fact that I had set the data type to a nvarchar() instead of int.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check your column to be a primary key(PK).
Also table creation script will help a lot.

Comment: Thanks, but I found the answer now.